# Java not working after upgrade to El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, osx-elcapitan

my java isn't working anymore, since upgrading to MacOS X El Capitan.

If i type "java -version" in the Terminal i will receive a popup telling me, that i have to install java from the Website.

After downloading and installing the jre8_60 the problem still persists.

Anyone have a clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Install the JDK not the JRE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So according to: https://oliverdowling.com.au/2015/10/09/oracles-jre-8-on-mac-os-x-el-capitan/
the .dmg for mac is not working.

But with the guide on this site it is possible to install the JRE8_60 with the .tar.gz version of the java download.

Answer (score -1):

It's best to install the JDK (Java Development Kit) rather than the JRE (Java Runtime Environment) when programming in Java.

The difference?

**JRE:** *Java Runtime Environment.* It is basically the Java Virtual Machine where your Java programs run on. It also includes browser plugins for Applet execution.

**JDK:** *Java Development Kit.* It's the full featured Software Development Kit for Java, including JRE, and the compilers and tools (like JavaDoc, and Java Debugger) to create and compile programs.